# Custom table component in .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, components

How do I create a custom table in C#, where i'd be able to set up row titles? Is there a built-in component to do that?

I'm currently migrating from Delphi, where there was a StringGrid component. So I wonder if there's such equivalent in .net.

As for now, I've tried to play DataGridView, but as far as I understood, it lacks row header (title) assignment. Am I missing something?

**Update**. Here's what actually needed:

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [piccy.info](http://i.piccy.info/i4/12/2e/7c196dfaf1fcabbf6613c05879ab.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use a TemplateField as the first column and fill it with your data in the `RowDataBound` event

Comment: Can you give an example or a link to one?

Comment: You could've Googled it yourself: http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-12-cs.aspx